# Find steady state of AIDS epidemic model

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state, population-dynamics

#### AIDS epidemic in a homosexual population

The following diagram shows the AIDS epidemic in a homosexual population:

[image]

Then the model can be described by
$$
\begin{gathered}
d X / d t=B-\mu X-\lambda c X \\
d Y / d t=\lambda c X-(v+\mu) Y \\
d A / d t=p v Y-(d+\mu) A \\
d Z / d t=(1-p) v Y-\mu Z \\
\textrm{Where }N(t)=X(t)+Y(t)+Z(t)+A(t)
\end{gathered}
$$

The system evolves to a steady state given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
X^*&=\frac{(v+\mu) N^*}{c \beta},\\Y^*&=\frac{(d+\mu)\left(B-\mu N^*\right)}{p v d},\\ Z^*&=\frac{(1-p)(d+\mu)\left(B-\mu N^*\right)}{p d \mu},\\
A^*&=\frac{\left(B-\mu N^*\right)}{d},\\ N^*&=\frac{B \beta[\mu(v+d+\mu)+v d(1-p)]}{(v+\mu)[\beta(d+\mu)-p v]} .
\end{aligned}
$$

But the problem is, I can solve the $\frac{dX}{dt}=0,\frac{dY}{dt}=0,\frac{dA}{dt}=0,\frac{dZ}{dt}=0$ simultaneously but couldn't bring the format of those states. I need to do this computation in the exam, so it will be a great help if anyone gives any suggestions or ways to make the computation quick.

Comment: I can do up to this @Moo but as you notice those states where given in terms of model parameter and N only. There I face the difficulty.

Comment: I haven't encountered that situation @Moo But I guess then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}$ will be helpful